# Which user is used to authenticate with the NFS server when mounting in fstab?

Tags: permissions, user, nfs

I'm trying to wrap my head around connecting my Pi2B to a NAS using NFS.  In [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87057/cannot-automatically-mount-nfs-share-to-raspberry-pi), @Ingo wrote.

> As customary then you mount to nfs shares with entries in
> `/etc/fstab`. This line in your `/etc/fstab` should do it:
> `192.168.1.152:/nfs/Music   /home/pi/nas   nfs   _netdev,auto   0   0`

But which user requires permissions on the NAS to mount this drive?  No one is logged on at this point, are they?

Comment: It's the `root` user of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `root` user `mount`s the drive. After it is mounted, the **permissions** on the NFS server will apply on a *per-user* basis.

---

With respect to the related question, `How Do I Setup User Permissions On My NFS Server`?

You can find these answers for the price of an [Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=configure+NFS+debian&ia=web), or this may provide [what you need.](https://vitux.com/debian_nfs_server/)

Comment: Does the same thing apply when a user is logged on: it's still mounted by `root`?  In other words, if I get something working whilst logged on, and then put the same command in `fstab`, it should still work?

Comment: @serialhobbyist: Don't confuse yourself. All I was trying to say was that `root` **privileges** are required to **mount** a device. Once it is mounted, the individual user's privileges will determine if that user may `read`, `write` or `execute` files and directories on the `mount`-ed volume.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate the answer of *@Seamus*, you have to differentiate between the mount action and the access to the mount point. in principle these have nothing to do with each other. Following the Unix paradigma "everything is a file", a remote filesystem is mounted to a local directory so you can access its content like local files. So mounting the filesystem is just doing that. By default this can only be done with root rights. With entries in `/etc/fstab` mounting is done by the operating system at boot up and the operating system uses root rights for this.

It is possible to mount filesystems with user rights, but that needs additional helper programs or entries in `/etc/fstab` (options *user*, or *users*) but that is out of scope here. Have a look at `man mount`.

As already said, mounting has nothing to do with access rights to the mount point. If you have mounted a filesystem with whatever rights then you will see the access rights that have been setup before on the filesystem or given by the sharing process (nfs with `/etc/exports`, samba with `/etc/samba.conf`, etc.). After a mount just look at its rights with, e.g.

```
rpi ~/$ sudo ls -la /mnt
```

Comment: But if I run `sudo mount //192.168.0.20/video/tv /mnt/nas/tv` it responds with: `Password for root@//192.168.0.200/video/tv:`.  I get what you're saying about root rights on the local machine but it appears to want root access to the NAS, as well.

Comment: @serialhobbyist This seems to be a configuration issue on the nfs server. On a linux box you would look at `/etc/exports` with doku in `man exports` and focus on `root_squash`, but also other options.

Comment: @serialhobbyist: Your question seems to have *morphed* into `How Do I Setup My NFS Server`? That's moving into **off-topic** territory... I'd tell you if I knew, but you can find these answers for the price of an [Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=configure+NFS+debian&ia=web), or you may find [what you need here](https://vitux.com/debian_nfs_server/)